# Angular 5: Argument of type 'void' is not assignment to parameter of type '{} | PromiseLike<{}>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-promise

---

This is my code:

```
public resetDefaults() {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(
      this.resetFilters()
    )
  }).then(()=> {return this.cachedFilters});
}

private resetFilters() {

}
```

The `this.resetFilters()` is giving me :

> *Argument of type 'void' is not assignment to parameter of type '{} | PromiseLike<{}>'*

I know that if I do:

```
private resetFilters(): Promise<any> {

}
```

It would get rid of that error but then I have to create a new promise in that method. I just want to be able to call a function without having to add any more promises. 
**I do need the Promise in `resetDefaults()` though**

Comment: Can you include a dummy implementation of `resetFilters`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `any` :

```
private resetFilters() : any {

}
```